# Array as list converted to binary

Tags: java, arrays, list, binary

What I'm trying to do is generate a new array as list and have it be sorted in ascending order and then having all the sorted integers of the array converted to their binary representation by the use toBinaryString

Here is what i have so far

```
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class binaryArray 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 12, 67, 1, 34, 9, 78, 6, 31, 81, 16});
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(list));

        }
}
```

Is it even possible to use toBinaryString to implement this the way i want it to?
Thanks.

Comment: Note that the parameter passed to method Integer.toBinaryString is an int value rather than an int List. You need write a loop for this List and call method Integer.toBinaryString for each int element in the list.

Comment: Does not compile. "The method toBinaryString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (List)"

Comment: You'd better declare the List as List<Integer> and write a loop for this list to handle each element in this list. Code is as follow:    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 12, 67, 1, 34, 9, 78, 6, 31, 81, 16});
     Collections.sort(list);
     for(Integer element :  list)
     {
      System.out.println(element);
     }

Comment: @MouseLearnJava - Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @DavidWallace - Firstly, I just want to point out that type List ( such as List<Integer> ) can not be passed to method Integer.toBinaryString. Would like to provide this as a hint. So I just added this as comments here.

Comment: Right.  I didn't even notice that you didn't have the call to `toBinaryString`.  But it seems to me that you have the makings of a solution which is different enough from Evans' solution that it would be worth having here.  I'm not thinking of user2924294, who may well have left the building; I'm thinking of future people coming to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you need to do it for each integer in the list

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(list.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((int) list.get(i))); but still you lead me to the solution. Thanks.